# Where does $r=\sin(\theta) d(\theta)$ come from when deriving the surface area of a sphere?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I'm practicing with Gauss's Law for my exam but I forgot how (especially) the sin (theta) was derived. I'm sure we derived this in one of my previous math classes but I forgot. I tried looking for answers online but it didn't help.

The derivation is done using a surface integral (by Divergence Theorem).

Comment: Jacobians. You probably mean $r^2\sin\theta$.

Comment: It's the Jacobian of the change of coordinates from Cartesian to spherical.

Comment: [As they said](http://www.math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/jacpol/jacpol.html)

Comment: Ah, this may sound disappointing but I don't know of any Jacobian term in math. I tried looking it up just now and we weren't taught this method exploiting determinants. I mean differential surface dS  is supposed to be (r*sin(theta) * d(theta)) * (r * d(phi))

Comment: @solitude: I wrote an example of the Jacobian below, for the coordinate change from ( a subset of) $\mathbb R^2$ with standard Cartesian, to $\mathbb R^2$ with polar coordinates. Maybe you can generalize it for your case.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Further_examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thisis the result of using the Jacobian under a coordinate change; when you go from a coordinate system $(x,y)$, to $(x',y')$ , the integral is scaled by the Jacobian of the coordinate-change functions $f_i; i=1,2,3$. Consider a simpler case of going from  standard to polar coordinates in (a subset of ) $\mathbb R^2$ (there is no global coordinate change between the two). Since you're going from the standard $(x,y)$ to $(x',y')=(rcos\theta, rsin\theta)$, the Jacobian of the transformation is $r$. Sorry, I don't know how to enter a matrix, but the Jacobian here is the $2 \times 2$ matrix whose first row is $$\partial/\partial r(rcos\theta)         \partial/\partial \theta cos\theta$$ ,

And the second row is  $$\partial/\partial r(rsin\theta)    \partial/\partial \theta sin\theta$$

Check that the determinant is $r$. Now you can do the same when you go from "standard" Cartesian to spherical coordinates'just use the determinant of the Jacobian of the coordinate change functions.

Comment: But why do Jacobian transformations even work? I know it has to do with a determinant area problem.